# install_version breaks symlinks in the renv library

Tags: r, renv

I use [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/index.html) to manage R package dependencies. The global cache works great for all packages that are installed with `install.packages` command; however, if I install the same package with `devtools::install_version` command it only installs it locally. As a result, any changes in the version number require manual installations again and again.
Do you have any idea how to address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem with my approach. Instead of using `install_version`, I should have used `renv::install()`. Here is an example:

Instead of using:

```r
devtools::install_version(package="BART", version = "2.2")
```

Use

```r
renv::install("BART")
renv::install("BART@2.2")
```